# Polymer ready vs attached callbacks with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm working on a Polymer app with Chart JS. Currently I have a custom element for my chart. I used a test dataset to test the element. When I initialize the canvas element for Chart.js inside the ready callback (which is the callback [Polymer recommends you to use](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#ready-method) when the element is "ready" and you need to manipulate the DOM), nothing shows up. However, when I add it to the attached callback, the chart properly initializes. Why doesn't it properly initialize in the ready callback?

**cnsmpo-graph.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
<script src="../../bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/Chart.Scatter.js/Chart.Scatter.js"></script>

<dom-module id="cnsmpo-graph">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <paper-material>
      <canvas id="chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </paper-material>
  </template>

</dom-module>

<script>
(function() {
  Polymer({
    is: 'cnsmpo-graph',

    properties: {
      foo: {
        type: String,
        value: 'bar',
        notify: true
      }
    },

    attached: function () {
      var data = {
        labels: [1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 100, 250],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [
              { x: 3, y: 10}
            ]
          }
        ]
      };
      var element = this.$.chart.getContext('2d');
      var chart = new Chart(element).Scatter(data, {bezierCurve: false,});
    }
  });
})();
</script>
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="generator" content="Polymer Starter Kit" />
  <title>Polymer Starter Kit</title>
  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

  <!-- Chrome for Android theme color -->
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#303F9F">

  <!-- Web Application Manifest -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <!-- Tile color for Win8 -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="application-name" content="Polymer Starter Kit">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Polymer Starter Kit">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/touch/apple-touch-icon.png">

  <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144) -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">

  <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <!-- endbuild-->

  <!-- build:js bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js -->
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <link rel="import" href="../styles/app-theme.html">
  <link rel="import" href="cnsmpo-graph/cnsmpo-graph.html">

  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
  <span id="browser-sync-binding"></span>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <cnsmpo-graph></cnsmpo-graph>
  </template>

  <!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild-->
</body>

</html>
```

Much of the code in the head of index.html is from the Polymer Starter Kit.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that Chart.js computes the size (width and height) of the context element that is passed to it upon initalisation. In the case of the `ready` callback, the element exists, but has not been added to the document yet. However, the computation done in Chart.js assumes that the element is already in the document. It uses `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(dimension)`.
Hence, it fails. When you use the `attached` callback the element has been added to the document and the computation is successful.